# How to revoke a token generated by msal4j?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-security

Using the Library `msal4j` I received a JWT token from Azure Active Directory and now, I would like to revoke that token. I didn´t find many information about how to do it.

Reference:
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/operationalize/how-to-manage-access-tokens#revoke-refresh-tokens

Many thanks in advance

Juan Antonio

Comment: Why do you need to revoke a token? There exists a function on MS Graph API to revoke refresh tokens, but that is really only meant to be used if you think the user account is compromised etc. For logout, just redirecting the user to log out with AAD is enough.

Comment: Hi, any other concern about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The reference you provided just applies to the refresh token from Machine Learning Server, if you want to revoke a specific refresh token from Azure AD, there is no such way currently, you can just revoke all the refresh token for a user.

You could use the options below:

- Microsoft Graph - [user: invalidateAllRefreshTokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-invalidateallrefreshtokens?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http&viewFallbackFrom=graph-rest-1.0) (Not recommend to use it in the production env, it is a Beta version)
- Azure AD Graph - [Invalidate all refresh tokens for a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#invalidate-all-refresh-tokens-for-a-user)
- Powershell command - [`Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/revoke-azureaduserallrefreshtoken?view=azureadps-2.0)

BTW, as mentioned in the comment,  this operation is performed (by the user or an administrator) if the user has a lost or stolen device typically, for logout, just redirecting the user to log out with AAD is enough.